# How to do non-subsequent URL rewriting in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to extract `jsessionid` from a sampler's response and reuse it for a third sampler. The sampler in between these two is an independent HTTP request which must not utilize any `jsessionid`s.

I'm able to do this ***manually*** using a "Regular Expression Extractor" for the first sampler and requesting for `jsessionid=${foobar}` in the third sampler:

[image]

However, I'd like to accomplish this using the components specifically engineered for this purpose, like *"[Pre Processor → HTTP URL Re-writing Modifier](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-adv-web-test-plan.html#session_url_rewriting)"* and etc.

How can we do URL rewriting for non-subsequent requests?

---

<sup>• Adding   "HTTP URL Re-writing Modifier" to the third sampler doesn't work, because it will attempt to parse the response from the second sampler instead of the first one.</sup>

<sup>• Adding "HTTP URL Re-writing Modifier"  to the second sampler doesn't work too, because while it is able to extract the `jsessionid` successfully, it uses that `jsessionid` for the second sampler instead of the third one.</sup>

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your problem so that we can see the order and arrangement of your samplers and assertions?

Comment: @djangofan, Ok, added screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

[JSESSIONID is usually a cookie](http://www.cs-repository.info/2014/07/understanding-jsessionid.html) so you can use JMeter's [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) to refer its value.

1. Add `CookieManager.save.cookies=true` line to *user.properties* file (it resides under /bin folder of your JMeter installation)
2. Add HTTP Cookie Manager to your Test Plan
3. Restart JMeter
4. Refer "jsessionid" value as `${COOKIE_JSESSIONID}` where required

Comment: Hi, yes the usual implementation for sessions is using cookies, but in this case it's using URL rewriting, not cookies. The server does not send `Set-Cookie` at all and the sessions work even if the browser has cookies disabled. As such, while step 4 works on the sever when it uses cookies, it instead uses the literal string `${COOKIE_JSESSIONID}` (because there are no matching cookies returned) when the server uses HTTP rewriting.

Comment: That sounds very unusual, and somewhat insecure for a site to implement sessions that way.

Comment: @djangofan,  It's not unusual at all, and that's the only way to do [sessions without cookies](https://www.google.com/search?q=session+without+cookies).  It's the same as `PHPSESSID` with `session.use_cookies = 0`.